# How to control shared internet connection (ICS - Internet Connection Sharing) using LSP/SPI?

Tags: windows, tcp, routes, winsock-lsp

I am trying to write an application for myself to learn things and to use in my own office. What I am trying to write is:

- I have two nics. First one is connected to internet and the other one is connected to network
- I have enabled ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) in my own PC
- Other computers (Laptops, iPads etc.) are connecting to internet using my PC
- So my c works like a hotspot

I am trying to see where they are connecting to and log their IP and MAC address. If I can do this, I will also add sign-in function at future.

Actually, my LSP supports TCP, UDP and RAW protocols. It works both on x86 and x64 Windows OS (Tested on Windows 7). However, when I connect to internet through this PC using my iPad, it doesn't seem working. WSPStartup never called.

If you have any idea, I will be more than happy.

Bests,

Comment: Any ideas about this question?

Comment: I believe  the connection request from you iPad to the PC never reached to the Winsock layer. It might be redirected by ICS at packet layer.  A wireshark capture on PC can help you identify this.

Comment: Well it is not easy to do that. I have only found solution using RAW sockets but I can only snif network. This is not actually what I need. What I need is to manage the traffic... It seems almost impossible with LSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NDIS, a library like WinPCAP would do the work.